# Correlated subqueries, max

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a complex query to extract data based on specific versions. I have a main subquery to specify my criteria to limit data and identify the max version of given record. Now, I have multiple tables, subqueries that I need to join to extract all the data I need, all the data I extract using the subqueries and other tables need to have the version# <= version in the main query. I have a sample query listed below:

```
select 
    a.id, b.item, c.value, n.notes 
from
    (select 
         id, max(version) mv over partition by id 
     from 
         t1 
     where 
         trunc(date) = '25-Oct-2017') a,
    (select 
         id, version bv, item 
     from 
         t2) b,
    (select 
         id, version cv, value 
     from 
         t3) c,
    (select 
         id, version nv, notes 
     from 
         t8) n
where
    b.id(+) = a.id
    and b.bv <= a.mv
    and c.id(+) = a.id
    and c.cv <= a.mv
    and n.id(+) = a.id
    and n.nv <= a.mv
```

My subqueries b, c, n etc, sometimes return multiple versions for a record, how do I get a max of the version in that scenario, however, the max may not be > a.mv

P.S: I know I am supposed to use the new join syntax, I am still learning to use that

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear. What is a "record" (returned by a subquery)? In common usage, "record" means "row"; what do you mean by "multiple versions for a row"? I assume you mean something different, but I can't tell what. Then: whatever you need, why can't you return a MAX the same way as you do in subquery **a**? Finally, if you are using old join syntax, use it correctly. If you need an outer join (as you seem to do), you need to add the `(+)` EVERYWHERE a column from subqueries **b**, **c** and **n** appears, not just once per alias. So, for example: `and b.bv(+) <= a.mv` etc.

Comment: Avoid (+) notation for outer joins.Use `join on` syntax even if your boss insists otherwise!

Comment: @mathguy: I meant to say multiple versions based on the id, I am unable to do a max as I need the version to be <= the max from a, I am unable to figure out how to get the max from a in the subquery.

Comment: You can't have a subquery in the select part that returns more then one column (or more then one row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after you fix the syntax (to have a proper outer join so that all the ID's from **a** will be present in the final output even if the ID is not found in the other subqueries), you now have many rows per ID, but with `a.mv` being the max version per `id` in `t1`.

That is good. Now, you need to group by ID, and select the item with the highest value from `b` (*after* you already filtered by `version <= a.mv'), etc.

So this sounds like an aggregate query (aggregate after the join, grouping by ID), but the problem is that you don't want the MAX(VERSION) from the other subqueries. You also **don't** want MAX(ITEM) or MAX(VALUE), etc. Rather, you want the item from the MAX(VERSION), the value from the MAX(VERSION) (in a *different* subquery), etc.

The condition that the versions from `b`, `c`, `n` is already in your `where` clause (after you fix the outer-query issue I pointed out).

So, all you need is an aggregate function that for some reason many developers are not familiar with, even though it is in the SQL Standard (and therefore it exists in most database products, not just in Oracle): the FIRST/LAST aggregate function.

```
select a.id, max(b.item)  keep (dense_rank LAST order by b.version) as item,
             max(c.value) keep (dense_rank LAST order by c.version) as version, etc.
from   your outer-join of four subqueries
where  (...)
group by a.id
;
```

Comment: I actually need the max for the versions in the subquery before, so I can compare the max version in the join, b.version<= a.mv etc.

Comment: If a.version returns 10, and b.version returns 3,7,12, for the same id, I need to get max(b.version) <= a.version, so that would be 7. How do I acheive that?

Comment: @Skn - I don't understand the question. Aren't you **already** selecting the max version in t1 in the subquery you aliased as **a**? Then in the join, you are only keeping the rows from t2, t3, t4 that have version less than the max(version) from t1 (for each ID separately).

Comment: but in my subqueries b,c,etc, there still may be multiple versions returned for the same id, I want to get a max of those versions that is <= the max version in a.

Comment: @Skn - "of those versions that is <= the max version in a" is taken care of by the inequalities in the WHERE clause. But you don't want to get the max of those versions, do you? You only want the ITEM that corresponds to the max version (of those versions that are <= max version in a) etc. This is exactly what the aggregate LAST function does. Did you try the suggested approach?

Comment: I tried this approach, when I run the complete query, it gives me this error - snapshot too old: rollback segment number 118 with name too small.

Comment: @Skn - **Huh???** What does your query have to do with *Snapshot too old: rollback segment number ...*? In any case, that has nothing to do with the correctness of the solution to the question you asked! There was no mention of "rollback" and such in your question. Don't move the goal posts; if you have another question, open a new thread.

Comment: I do not, this is just a plain select query, somehow I got this error after the query ran for about 2hrs.

Comment: @Skn - I haven't encountered this situation myself, but a bit of Googling shows that his error may happen if you are running your query (which may take a few minutes, say) while someone else is modifying the same table or tables (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) and the rollback segments are not sized properly. Something to discuss with your DBA. Discussion on AskTom here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3A0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11%5FQUESTION%5FID:1441804355350